# Term for how long a program takes to run

Tags: performance, terminology

I just want the word for how long a program takes to run (like when you actually run it, not time complexity). I suspect its "running time" but when I google running time, google gives me a bunch of stuff about runtime, so I am stuck.

For example: "The _____ of my program is 2100ms."

Comment: “Run time” or “run-time”.

Answer (score 3):

Runtime, run time, or execution time would work.

> In computer science, runtime, run time, or execution time is the final
> phase of a computer program's life cycle, in which the code is being
> executed on the computer's central processing unit (CPU) as machine
> code. In other words, "runtime" is the running phase of a program.

(according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_(program_lifecycle_phase)))

Comment: I thought those referred to the compilation process, i.e., the java compiler compiles code at runtime. The runtime of my program won't be a number, it will be a phase in the compilation process, right?

Comment: @WillKanga it is a phase/state and also a term of measurement.

Comment: @WillKanga The "runtime" you speak of is part of the execution phase of a program. Not all programs have a "runtime environment" like Java does. It's not a compilation process, it's more of a program that manages the program. For example, the Java garbage collector is part of its "runtime". You can read more about it on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system